# Liferay: How to create a organization programatically?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I am well versed with the `liferay` portal. But i dont know how do i create a `organization` when it comes to programming through `liferay developer studio.` Can it be done through a `hook`?. For now i have a project available in which i have created a `hook`. Which interface should i implement and what all `classes` should i be using it. What i have done till now?
 I have gone through this [link](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.html#addOrganization%28long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20long,%20long,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext%29) which makes us understand about the methods but the approach required is missing. I couldnt find it anywhere(basics and approach of creating org through program). What are the entries that i have to make in `liferay-hook.xml`?

I am a beginner and any guidance is much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Contradicting statement in your question. 1) Well versed 2) Am a beginner ;)

Comment: Not Contradicting actually..I said i am well versed with the portal but not with the Developer studio..There i am a beginner..:)

Answer (score 1):

Liferay provides Utility classes, which are usable/callable outside the ROOT context of the server.

Generally you can find those classes with following post-fix: **entity-name-ServiceUtil**

For Organization you have **OrganizationLocalServiceUtil**, which have related methods e.g. **OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.addOrganization(...)**
to add the organization.

If you want to try this thing out, create a simple liferay portlet and check the method.

One can use these methods in HOOK, Portlet or Ext depending on the use-case.

Answer (score 0):

@Shirish You can use liferay utility classes anywhere like inside hook,ext ...etc.

Here you want to create organization inside hook, which you can accomplish using utility class `OrganizationServiceUtil` in following way.

```
ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(request); //or null
Organization organization = OrganizationServiceUtil.addOrganization(
                OrganizationConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID,
                organizationName,
                OrganizationConstants.TYPE_REGULAR_ORGANIZATION,
                RegionConstants.DEFAULT_REGION_ID,
                CountryConstants.DEFAULT_COUNTRY_ID,
                ListTypeConstants.ORGANIZATION_STATUS_DEFAULT,
                "",
                false,
                serviceContext
        );
```

You can also create organization using Utility class '`OrganiztionLocalServiceUtil`' in following way.

```
OrganiztionLocalServiceUtil.addOrganization(
    long userId, long parentOrganizationId, String name, String type,
    boolean recursable, long regionId, long countryId, int statusId,
    String comments, boolean site, ServiceContext serviceContext);
```

Comment: Dont we make any declarations under liferay-hook.xml?

Comment: what kind of declarations u want?

Comment: Interface and service related declarations that we are going to use?

Comment: Nope, `portal-service.jar` present in your `/tomcat/lib/ext` contains everything that we need to use.

Comment: Thanks buddy for the guidance..And i will accept the answer once i implement the changes..